# SQLExpress instance seems to be absent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server Express instance on my laptop; I have SQL Server 2008 installed in my system, but when I try to put the instance `(local)/SQLEXPRESS` or `Jashobanta-PC/SQLEXPRESS` in my system, I am not able to connect to it. It is appearing that it is not even present in my system.

I am getting the following error  :-

> *A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..*

I have tried using the `SQLCMD` command tool also for this, but the result is same:-

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS
```

Here also the same error is appearing.

Is there any chance that `SQLEXPRESS` is not installed in my system? But as MVC Code First uses SQL Server Express, I need it. When I use code first, then the files are created fine, but how it is connecting, where it is creating the database, it is not known.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance
Jashobanta

Comment: Yes, it is possible that SQL Server Express isn't installed. Did you install it? When? Is it running? What shows in SQL Server Configuration Manager (or is there a service named SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) in Administrative Tools > Services)?

Comment: I have tried checking all the protocols. All the protocols except VIA are enabled. And there is no setting where Protocols for SQLExpress are there.

Comment: No Aron, there is no service called SQLEXPRESS in Services.....But it comes as default with Visual Studio 2010, and I have sql server 2008 installed in the system. So I don't know how it got missed.

Comment: Please show a screen shot of the SQLEXPRESS service in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services.

Comment: So if there is no service called SQLEXPRESS, why do you expect to be able to connect to one? I'm going to go get groceries in my Ferrari. Oh wait, I don't have a Ferrari!

Comment: But how to install the thing? I tried installing SQL Server Express but it is opening the modify existing installation window in SQL Server 2008. And on progressing to modify, all the checkboxes are already checked, so no chances of changing the installation.

Comment: Sorry, very hard to determine what you are doing, what state your installation is in, and how you "tried installing" from the commentary. If all else fails, go [download a more modern version of SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) and install a new instance. You may have to name it something other than SQLEXPRESS, and that's ok.

Comment: It is done. Had to install the sqlexpress from the visual studio installation directory. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this, so for google purposes I'll list my result.

My take on the problem was that I had a SQL2008 Express instance, that had 'gone dark' because I'd installed a full instance of SQL2008R2 and/or SQL Express 2012. My guess is that one or the other of these turns off the out-of-date express instance as a security risk.

These instances were installed as fresh instance names, but somewhere along the way my `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` instance was disabled.

Using this [link](http://blog.meaalmcommunity.com/post/2013/01/11/sql-server-2012-express-install-a-new-instance.aspx) I used the SQL2008R2 installer to upgrade the `SQLEXPRESS` instance that the installer detected.

Once the `SQLEXPRESS` instance was upgraded to 2008R2 it was happily re-enabled and accessible at `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`, with all my previous databases inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem just now. What you need to do to resolve the problem is to install SQL Server 2008 Express edition.

You can do this by searching "SQL Express" from Web Platform Installer and install "SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Series" and "SQL Server 2008 Express with Tools".

Or

Download from this url and install.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695

`.\SQLEXPRESS` is SQL Express for SQL Server 2008 while
`(LocalDB)\v11.0` is SQL Express for SQL Server 2012 / 14